# how this function is working without parameters?

Tags: python, function, parameters, arguments

```
def add1():
    c=a+b
    print("sum is",c)

a=int(input("Enter a:"))
b=int(input("Enter b:"))
add1()
```

the program is about adding two numbers. and displaying result.
I took a and b input from the user, and directly called the function without passing arguments.
its working. Could you please explain why this is workig?

I'm also confused when to use arguments and when not?

Answer (score 1):

Variable a and b are global as they are not declared in any indent, so all your function does is add variable a and b if you named your variable any thing other than a it b it would not work

Comment: Thanks bro for solution, i'm begginner in python

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).